# Dropdown menu cut-off when using over-flow with scroll

Tags: html, css

I am making a item container which have many item boxes in there, when I hover the item, it will have a drop-down table for item-informations.

The problem here is that I when I set the container to overflow:auto (so that I can store as many boxes as I want) then when I hover at the box, the drop down will be cut-off in a very ridiculous way. What i want is that the dropDown will be all visible, you guys have any trick to make this?

[image]

```css
.parent{
overflow-y:auto;
background-color: blue;
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}



.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Item1</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p>Info 1</p>
      <p>Info 2</p>
      <p>Info 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.parent{
overflow-y:auto;
background-color: blue;
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.dropDownContainer {
  display:block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
  position: static;
}



.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="dropDownContainer">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Item1</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p>Info 1</p>
      <p>Info 2</p>
      <p>Info 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but this only work with 1 boxes only, if change attr to position: absolute then I have to position every boxes I add after, I just want to use float:left so they can stack easily.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<style>
    .parent{
background-color: blue;
width: 500px;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}



.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
</style>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Item1</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p>Info 1</p>
      <p>Info 2</p>
      <p>Info 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem is that I have to keep overflow-y:auto so that I can add more boxes to the container, I thought I have said this quite clear in my description above

Answer (score -3):

You need to change `overflow-y:auto` to `overflow-y:visible` on `.parent div` or else you can remove that property from .parent div.

Comment: Problem is that I have to keep overflow-y:auto so that I can add more boxes to the container, I thought I have said this quite clear in my description above